# append textbox value and checkbox value to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble figuring out how to append the values in the text field(exclude empty textboxes and corresponding checkboxes) and all the checked and unchecked values to a string in the order: name|T|F_name|F|F

I have this code, I have been trying to figure out how to make it into a single string. On submit I will send this string to my controller.

```
<input type="text" value="jim">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox">
<input id="button_1" type="button" value="delete" ><br>
<input type="text" >
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input id="button_2" type="button" value="delete"><br>
<input type="text" value="deb">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="button_3" type="button" value="delete"><br>
<input type="submit">


$(':input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "") { 
        nameString = $(this).val();

});

$(':checked').each(function() {

});
```

**UPDATE**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7JZF/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 2 for loops as I believe you want it results per line. check http://jsfiddle.net/s7JZF/7/

**Note:** I have added conditions to exclude row if the textbox is empty.

```
var results = [],
    delimiter = '|';

$('table tr').each(function () {
    var line = [];
    $(this).find('input').each(function () {
        if (this.type == 'text') {
            //exclue blank textbox
            if (this.value == '') return false;

            line.push(this.value);
        } else if (this.type == 'checkbox') {
            line.push(this.checked?'T':'F');
        }
    });

    if (line.length) {
        results.push(line.join(delimiter));
    }
});

alert(results.join('_'));
```

Comment: Thanks so much... this works like a charm !. What was the mistake in the jsfiddle code ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var results = [], delimiter = '|', n, c;
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    n = this.value;
    if (n !== ''){
        c = that.nextUntil('input[type="button"]').map(function(){
            return this.checked == true;
        }).get().join(delimiter);
        results.push(n,c);
    }
});

console.log(results.join(delimiter));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s7JZF/).

The above does rely, somewhat, on the structure of your HTML (specifically the `radio` elements coming before the button(s).

If you need the `true`/`false` to be `T`/`F`, then instead use:

```
var results = [], delimiter = '|', n, c;
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    n = this.value;
    if (n !== ''){
        c = that.nextUntil('input[type="button"]').map(function(){
            return (this.checked == true).toString().toUpperCase().slice(0,1);
        }).get().join(delimiter);
        results.push(n,c);
    }
});

console.log(results.join(delimiter));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s7JZF/1/).

References:

- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [`Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).
- [`String.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Comment: in the jsfiddle example your code works excellent, but your code in my code doesn't print the value of the checkbox. I am confused what is happening

Comment: Then you need to work out the differences between your code and the linked demonstrations; are there any errors generated in the console? What're the differences in JavaScript, or the html?

Comment: See the updated section. My actual html and your javascript function. The table is generated dynamically based on the resultset, so I am appending an integer at the end of the id to differentiate the item. For some reason the value of the checkbox is blank when I implement your code.

Comment: Within the `map()` method add a `console.log(this, this.value, this.checked);` `this` should be the `input` element, `this.value` should be `on` or `off`, `this.checked` should be either `true` or `false`. I'm unsure as to why the `input[type="text"]` selector should work, while the `checkbox`-es don't.

Comment: I see it empty.. I don't think its even getting into the `map` function

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle demo `http://jsfiddle.net/s7JZF/4/` to table and not it doesn't work with the checkbox elements. Can you let me know why it happens

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but there are a few minor changes you'll have to make if I understand your code correctly...

```
namestring = "";
$(':input[type="text"]').each(function() {
     if($(this).val() != "") { 
         namestring += $(this).val();
         $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
             if($(this).is(":checked"))
                 checked = T;
             else
                 checked = F;
             namestring += checked;
         }
         namestring += "_";
     }
}
//<Send namestring places>
```

This code should do what you are looking for, but I have not tested it.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/PuQ4r/

Comment: Its not attaching the checkbox value. I would be needing the checkbox value to be either T or F based on if it checked or unchecked

Comment: I would recommend using $(this).is(":checked") instead of checking the attribute value.

Comment: @TJC its returning false everytime for me, though the textbox is checked and I am getting the checkbox value as false for 6 times. I have 2 rows and the value is `nameFFFFFF_nameFFFFFF_`

Comment: do you ever close your input elements? i dont see any </input> tags in your code. this would throw off the code... also, i updated the if statement above.

Comment: @TJC I see whats happening. In the example code, I have a total of 6 checkboxes, first row is empty and so are its corresponding checkboxes, the code returns the value of all the checkboxes.

Comment: i think you need to namespace your HTML a little bit better, like put each row in its own div. This will make it a thousand times easier to iterate over it with jQuery.

Comment: I have put it in a table with text field, checkboxes and delete button as column elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PuQ4r/

There's a js fiddle that does what youre looking for, minus the omission of any without a val.

I wouldnt bother with a table, a div does what you need and is waaaaay cleaner.

Comment: @TJC Can we skip the checkbox values for the rows that has empty text field. I am using your code and everytime I have to validate the string to remove the checkbox values from the string that starts with FF after underscore

Comment: yeah definitely, its just an additional line. I updated the JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/PuQ4r/ 

if this works for you, please mark it as answered.

Comment: @TJC It's not working for me. See the case when the second text field is empty and the checkboxes are unchecked and the first text field has a value and one of the checkboxes is checked, this is the ans I get from your code jim|T|F_|F|F_deb|T|T_ I need to strip of the empty text box and checkbox values from the string and ans should be something like jim|T|F_deb|T|T_

Answer (score 0):

if you set the same name for each of your inputs, values will be sent as a string array.

so your server side controller (you didn't say which technology is) should pick em right away.

checkbox without checked value wont be sent by default.

you can 'preview' this doing a GET instead of POST form, so if you have :

```
<input name="form1" value="yes" type="text" />
<input name="form1" type="checkbox" value="sure" checked />
<input name="form1" type="checkbox" value="noway" />
```

a GET form will give you :

```
someAction?form1=yes&form1=sure
```

which in turn will be a string array on your server.

I know is not a direct answer, but a proper use of HTML input elements that may help in your situation.